# Hyperledger fabric channel configuration

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I would like to understand the information about the channel configuration. Is it stored in genesis block? What is the data structure of the genesis block? Any further update to channel configuration, will it be stored in new block? if I want to fetch the channel's latest configuration, is there any specific block I need to fetch?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run "peer channel fetch config" to retrieve the last configuration block of the channel. See https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/commands/peerchannel.html#fetch-syntax